# NULL returned from a function that returns an abstract class

Tags: c++, class, null

I have an abstract class called `Item`
and a function

`Item function(int x,int y);`

my question is can I return a NULL from that function?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you declared the return type as the class instance, no, you cannot return a pointer. NULL (should be nullptr) is a pointer.

If Item is an abstract class, the proper function design would be:

```
Item* function(int x,int y);
```